# Does gravity , say of another planet, affect the atomic mass and therefore the molar mass of water?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Does gravity , say of another planet, affect the atomic mass of elements and therefore the molar mass of water?

Comment: "Weight" depends on gravity, mass does not.

Answer (score 3):

So the concept that you're getting confused is the difference between weight and mass. Mass is a fundamental property of an object that is not affected by its position in the universe. Any electron proton and neutron has the EXACT same mass as any other electron proton or neutron in the whole universe.

Weight, on the other hand, is the **force** an object feels due to gravity. Remember Newton's Second Law of motion $F = ma$. On Earth, the acceleration due to gravity is roughly 9.8 $m /s^2$ so a 1 kg object feels a force of magnitude 9.8 Newtons pointed downward. If this same 1 kg object were on the Moon where the acceleration due to gravity is 1.6 $m/s^2$ it would feel a downward force of only 1.6 Newtons.

Now, I suspect your confusion arises because we measure mass using the force of gravity. However, imagine a classic balance. If we put a 1 kg object on one side and a 2kg object on the other side both will feel a downward force due to gravity; however, the ratio of the forces (which is what determines the position of the needle) will be independent of the force of gravity.